# App on iPhone shows installed but can't find it to open or uninstall

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, ios-appstore

I have a weird behavior with one of the apps on my iPhone. As you may see on the picture it's not installed but at the same time I can't seem to uninstall it because I can't find it on my iPhone, neither on the screens neither through search. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You talking about "Checkmate!" ?

Comment: @pjctech Yes, that one is giving me a headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an iMessage app.

How to delete an iMessage app:

1. Tap the App Store icon in the iMessage conversation view
2. Tap the apps icon on the bottom left (4 rounded grey rectangles)
3. Long-tap the app you want to delete (they’ll start wiggling)
4. Delete just like you’d delete any app on your phone
5. Done

[image: Delete iMessage app]